# Using case_when within a function

Tags: r

I am writing a function using case_when as exampled below:

```
library(tidyverse)

#what I want to happen
iris%>%
mutate(category=case_when(Petal.Length<1.5~"less than 1.5", 
                          TRUE~"other"))

#the function version
fn<-function(df, column){
df%>%
mutate(category=case_when(column<1.5~"less than 1.5", 
                                  TRUE~"other"))       
}

#trying to run the function
fn(iris, Petal.Length)
```

When I run the function I get the error message `object 'Petal.Length' not found` . Can anyone ammend the function so I can pass the name of the column into it?

Comment: The answer is to use {{ }} brackets: fn<-function(df, column){
    df%>%
        mutate(category=case_when({{column}}<1.5~"less than 1.5", 
                                  TRUE~"other"))       
}